# Special request on post and post_meta wordpress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Could you help me to request all attachment post (images) on the wordpress wp_posts table who has no related line on wp_post_meta table with meta_key="_wp_attachment_image_alt".

Something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` as post
left join `wp_postmeta` as meta ON post.ID = meta.post_id
WHERE `post_type`='attachment' AND (***no line on wp_metapost with meta_key="_wp_attachment_image_alt"***)
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you

```
global $wpdb;
$sql_query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts as post
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as meta ON post.ID = meta.post_id
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'attachment'
    AND
    (
        $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attachment_image_alt'
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value != ''
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    )"
);

print_r($sql_query);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Maximilian, but your request get all the post products who has _wp_attachment_image_alt attribute  on the postmeta table, and meta_value on it. I want to get all the products without _wp_attachment_image_alt attribut on postmeta table.